# Is there a way in PHP for me to specify that an array will consist only of certain types of objects?

Tags: php, arrays

For example suppose I have a Car object and I want my array to consist only of Cars.  Is there some syntax that allows me to do this?

Comment: Not with normal arrays, no. Maybe by extending [`ArrayObject`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.construct.php) though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. PHP does not have any strong typing.

The only way I can think of enforcing this would be to have a CarArray class that has getters,setters,etc.. functions that enforce the parameters to be of class Car.

Comment: Good thinking. There is an [ArrayObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.construct.php) class in the SPL that might help

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box not but you could implement [ArrayObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) on your `Car` class and override the append method of ArrayObject to only accept instances of `CarPart` for example. That way you have an object that behaves as an array and as long as you add items with append it will only accept items of the `CarPart` type.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a basic list class like the following, and only allow items to be added to the list using the `addItem` function in your code. You could probably add alot of functionality around it. And then carry out whatever array specific operations on the `$list->items` array you want using standard php array functionality.

```
class list()
{
    function __construct($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->items = array();
    }

    public function addItem($item)
    {
        if( get_class($item) == $type )
        {
            $this->items[] = $item;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap whatever you want to store the cars in with a typehinted API:

```
class Cars implements IteratorAggregate
{
    protected $storage;

    public function __construct(SplObjectStorage $storage)
    {
        $this->storage = $storage;
    }
    public function addCar(Car $car)
    {
        $this->storage->attach($car);
    }
    public function removeCar(Car $car)
    {
        $this->storage->detach($car);
    }
    public function getIterator()
    {
        return clone $this->storage;
    }
    // …
}
```

Whether you use [`SplObjectStorage`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php) or [`ArrayObject`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) or a plain `array` for `$storage` is up to you. It's the wrapper that's taking care of that nothing but `Cars` get into it.

[Full working example on codepad](http://codepad.org/GobaU9ni)

If you prefer to use array notation, e.g. square brackets, implement [`ArrayAccess`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php).

```
class Cars implements IteratorAggregate, ArrayAccess
{
    // …

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
    {
        if($value instanceof Car) {
            $this->storage[$offset] = $value;
        } else {
            throw …
        }
    }
}
```

[Full working example at codepad](http://codepad.org/geoc4TNW)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using an array filter to remove any objects that aren't cars.

```
// Return TRUE to keep the value, FALSE otherwise
function car_filter($val) {
    return ($val instanceof Car);
}

$cars = array( ... ); // an array of cars

// Apply the filter
$cars = array_filter($cars, "car_filter")
```